# Laravel VueJS bind dynamic quantity to each input in a products list component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Trying to create a dynamic form with a list of each product from a db. The form has the following fields for each product: product title, product price, quantity and total price. My issue is in the fact that I'm not sure how to add a v-model field for each product quantity input, since the list is being pulled from a v-for of all of the products. Here is part of my **ProductsListForm vue component** template:

```
<div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" class="flex form-group">

  <div class="flex p-title">
    <label :for="product.title">{{ product.title }}</label>
    <small>{{ product.price }}$</small>
  </div>

  <div class="flex p-input">
    <input class="input" type="number" :name="product.title" v-model="quantity">
  </div>

  <div class="flex p-total">
    <span>Total: {{  product.price * quantity}}</span>
  </div>

</div>


export default {
  props: ['products'],
  data() {
      return {
          quantity: 0,
      }
  },
  methods: {}
}
```

So my question is how can I bind *quantity* to each individual product? Right now, it obviously changes whenever ANY of the input fields are updated...
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `quantity` an information that each product has? Does it work when you refer to it as `product.quantity`?

Comment: `v-model`ing the property of an array item works, as you can see in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Yovar/nj0w7oye/3/

Comment: @Yovar `quantity` is unrelated to each product. It's a variable associated with the form itself. When I try to do it that way, the total is NaN

Comment: @Yovar the form is intended to act like a shopping list. A customer inputs how many of each product (quantity) so having quantity as a db field for each product is not the intended purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `v-model`, you could instead listen for the `input` events on each element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    cart: [],
    products: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'baz'
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    updateCart(event, product) {
      const index = this.cart.findIndex(i => i.name === product.name)

      const item = {
        name: product.name,
        quantity: event.target.value
      }

      if (index !== -1) {
        this.cart.splice(index, 1, item)
      } else {
        this.cart.push(item)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h5>products</h5>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
        <label>{{ product.name }}</label>
        <input @input="updateCart($event, product)" min="0" type="number">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>cart</h5>
    <ul v-if="cart.length">
      <li v-for="item in cart" :key="item.id">
        <p>{{ item.name }} {{ item.quantity }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p v-else>no items in cart</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the quantity to be related to the product (entry of products) - you will have to pass it to the products or make it an array by itself.

```
<div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" class="flex form-group">

  <div class="flex p-title">
    <label :for="product.title">{{ product.title }}</label>
    <small>{{ product.price }}$</small>
  </div>

  <div class="flex p-input">
    <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="1" :name="product.title" v-model="quantity[product.id]">
  </div>

  <div class="flex p-total">
    <span>Total: {{  product.price * getProductQuantity(product) }}</span>
  </div>

</div>


export default {
  props: ['products'],
  data() {
      return {
          quantity: [],
      }
  },
  methods: {
    getProductQuantity(product) {
      return this.quantity[product.id] || 0;
    }
  }
}
```